# Can I ignore CWWKS3005E messages on worklight server logs?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have an application running on Worklight 6.1 and I am seeing this messages on the log.

CWWKS3005E: A configuration exception has occurred. No UserRegistry implementation service is available

I don't need to authenticate the users on my application, can I ignore this message?

Comment: Could you provide some more details about your application and how to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try to cancel logging for this specific package using following log configuration in server.xml:

```
<logging traceSpecification="XXX.XXX.*=off=disabled"/>
```

where XXX.XXX.* is the package where the error was occurred.

Here is a list of all available log levels: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/utrb_loglevel.html

---

I understand that you are not asked how to remove these messages from the log file, but you asked should you worry about these messages.
Anyway this log is not of Worklight server, it generated by Liberty server. It means you have something wrong in server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this messages is because my server.xml configuration file of WebSphere Liberty Profile contains this feature

appSecurity-1.0

And I am not defining any User Registry.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html

I am not running the Application Center in this profile and I am securing the Worklight console using properties in the worklight.properties file.

So, the question is can I remove the appSecurity feature?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<basicRegistry></basicRegistry>` to your server.xml.